# How to return a method from a class?

Tags: python, methods

I have a class `Netflix` and a method `find_popular_category`. However I can't get the method to return the word I'm looking for.

```
class Netflix:
    def find_popular_category(self):
        path = os.path.abspath('../data/netflix.csv')
        with open(path, encoding= 'utf-8-sig') as file:
            open_file = csv.reader(file)
            next(file)

            lst = []
            for x in open_file:
                cate = x[10]
                lst.append(cate)

            spt = [category for word in lst for category in word.split(",")]  # splits every word in the string "list"

            word_count = Counter(spt)  # counts the categories
            most = word_count.most_common(1)  # gets most categories
            print(most)
            return most[0][0]


netflix = Netflix()
netflix.find_popular_category()
print(netflix)
```

Output:

```
[(' International Movies', 1842)]  # This is because of print(most).
<__main__.Netflix object at 0x000001C254E711C8>  
# Why doesn't it return only International Movies?
```

Comment: It *does* return it; you just don't do anything with it. You ignore the returned value and print the instance instead.

Comment: try   "result = netflix.find_popular_category()" and "print(result)"

Comment: `result = netflix.find_popular_category()` -you currently print the address of your function not the result of its invocation

Comment: You're not "returning a method" — and don't really want to — instead print the result of _calling_ it: `print(netflix.find_popular_category())`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are just printing the instance of the object. I would assign netflix.find_popular_category() to a variable and print that instead. For example

```
popularCategory = netflix.find_popular_category()

print(popularCategory)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to print the instance of the `Netflix` object. But you need to print the result of the function:

```py
print(netflix.find_popular_category())
```

Instead of:

```py
print(netflix)
```